# Extending signal cable

Tags: serial, cables

I have a signal cable (also transmits power) that is extremely short (see attached picture).

I would like to extend the cable with one meter (3ft), and I was thinking of cutting it in two (again see picture), and then attaching it to either a phone cable or a flat console (serial) cable, but I don't know how to best attach the cables.

How do I attach thin twisted cables so that I can extend my signal cable?

[image: Cut signal cable]

*Edit:* I have tried different ways of extending and done extensive testing that the signal survives (it does).  However, none are good "permanent" solutions.  The signal is 9600 baud, and the device draws minimal amounts (<1W) of power.

Comment: judging by wire gauge and length increase, would need twice the wire thickness, unless you provide some datasheet on load

Comment: First you should make sure the nature of these signals will survive the extension.

Comment: The best solution would be to get new crimp connectors to go in the connector bodies and completely replace the cable. Otherwise, you could slide heatshrink tubing over soldered connections to make it *look* ok. What environment is the cable to be used in?

Comment: Indeed, if you checked it works with phone cable, use that. Just solder each wire correctly, isolate each joint with two turns of isolating tape and put some heatshrink tube around the whole fix. If it is not exposed to frequent flexion, it will work forever (although this is very unprofessional). Fixed a lot of toys with that technique...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I have been doing it for decades...

[image: Wire Lap Joint NASA standards]